# how to authorize an user using jGit

Tags: java, jgit

I'm creating an application in Java and using jGit. As part of this I need to authenticate an user. I want to output if the user is existing or not. Currently I get an exception as `user is not authorized`. Below is my code.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;

public class AuthenticateanUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String REMOTE_URL = "https://myRepo.git";
        // prepare a new folder for the cloned repository
        File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
        localPath.delete();
        // then clone
        try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL)
                .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("myId", "myPwd"))
                .setDirectory(localPath).call()) {

            System.out.println("Having repository: " + result.status());
        }
    }

}
```

when I run my above code, If I give correct credentials, I get the output as

```
Having repository:XXXXX
```

if I give wrong credentials I get error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://myRepo.git: not authorized
```

Instead of this I want to print, Invalid credentials.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: @GhostCat my bad, should have done it in the first instance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go:

```
try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL) {
  ...         
} catch (TransportException te) {
     System.out.println("Invalid credentials");
}
```

for example.

You should *not* tell the user if the account exists or not. As in: if you tell that an attacker, he can conclude that he already got a valid username.

Comment: Thanks for the quick Answer @GhostCat. I've got another dumb question, what if the user is providing correct credentials, but he doesn't have any permissions to access that repo? how am I going to differentiate in this case? like, 2 different error messages... if not authenticated `Invalid Credentials` (as you have in your answer), and if not authorized to use a repo, `you are not authorized to use this repo`. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @user3872094 In that case, obviously, the credentials are correct. I would then just print that to the user (it could probably mean that you have to parse exception messages, or something alike. if possible, see if the the exception contains some numeric error code, or if the type of the underlying exception is a different one to properly identify the exact problem).

Comment: apologies for not yet accepting. I've got 1 last question, here in my case that I'm looking for, the user logs in, if he is logged in, i dont want to throw any exception, and show a message in `sysout` as logged in and proceed, currently if the user is not having an access *or* user enters invalid credentials, the exception is thrown. is there a way that I can restrict this thing? updated my question with additional info.

Comment: I dont get that last question. And sorry: dont do that. Dont play "one more question" in comments ping pong. When one question is done, then accept/upvote maybe the answer, and put up a new question. This site is Q&A site. Not a tutor forum, where people sit down with you to walk work you through your assignment.