# proceed with the code when user is authenticated successfully

Tags: java, exception, jgit

I'm creating an application in Java and using jGit (continuation to [how to authorize an user using jGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442064/how-to-authorize-an-user-using-jgit)). Currently I'm able to segregate the exceptions, I get `not authorized` if the user is giving invalid credentials and `repository not found` if the user is not having access to the repo declared. Now my issue is, the user is getting authenticated, as the user is not having access to the repo, the second exception is being thrown. But here I want to handle it in another class, i.e. I want this class only to handle user's authentication. Below is my code

```
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;

public class AuthenticateanUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String REMOTE_URL = "https://myRepo.git";
        // prepare a new folder for the cloned repository
        File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
        localPath.delete();
        // then clone
        try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL)
                .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("myId", "myPwd"))
                .setDirectory(localPath).call()) {

            System.out.println("Having repository: " + result.status());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("repository not found"))
            System.out.println("Exception Repo not found");
        else if (e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("not authorized"))
            System.out.println("Exception Invalid Credentials");
        else
            System.out.println(e);

    }
    }

}
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should chain exceptions and not work with top level Exception class. [GitAPIException](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/errors/GitAPIException.html) is thrown while cloning. You can try to catch possible cases first and let the main Exception deal with rest.

```
public static <R>R handleClone(String uri,File local,boolean bare,Function<Git,R> fn){
  try {
    Git g=Git.cloneRepository().setURI(uri).setBare(bare).setDirectory(local).call();
    return handle(g,fn);
  }
 catch (  GitAPIException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
  }
}
```

Exception Chaining example :

```
catch (  IOException e) {
    return new Status(IStatus.ERROR,GitActivator.PI_GIT,"Error cloning git repository",e);
  }
catch (  CoreException e) {
    return e.getStatus();
  }
catch (  GitAPIException e) {
    return getGitAPIExceptionStatus(e,"Error cloning git repository");
  }
catch (  JGitInternalException e) {
    return getJGitInternalExceptionStatus(e,"Error cloning git repository");
  }
catch (  Exception e) {
    return new Status(IStatus.ERROR,GitActivator.PI_GIT,"Error cloning git repository",e);
  }
  return Status.OK_STATUS;
}
```